# The Turing Test "It doesn't Add Up question"

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

> In the square below, change the position of six numbers, one per horizontal row, vertical column and long diagonal line of  six smaller squares, in such a way so the numbers in each row, column or diagonal line total exactly 246. Any number may appear more than once in each row, column or line.

Attribution: E Saunders, D. Turing [Expert Number Puzzles](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Turing-Expert-Number-Puzzles-puzzles/dp/1788887530/)

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39 | 13 | 24 | 25 | 68 | 39 |
| 38 | 44 | 66 | 15 | 41 | 45 |
| 41 | 74 | 41 | 23 | 41 | 46 |
| 33 | 49 | 41 | 59 | 20 | 59 |
| 36 | 43 | 21 | 58 | 39 | 45 |
| 63 | 26 | 49 | 28 | 57 | 27 |

Comment: Is this an original puzzle? If not, it requires proper attribution.

Comment: This exercise seems to have quite a lot of additions and not all that much actual puzzle solving to it.

Answer (score 6):

This puzzle is easier than it looks.

First you have to realise that

> In each column and each row, only one cell will be changed. So each changing cell will change its row sum and its column sum by the same amount, and those sums are not changed by any other cells. Therefore the row sums must match the column sums in some order, and their intersections are the cells that have to be changed.

We then simply look at the row and column sums:

> I have marked the cells that are in a row and column with an equal sum with hash signs.
>
> ```
>                                 250
>        39  13  24 #25# 68  39 | 208
>        38 #44# 66  15  41  45 | 249
>        41  74  41  23 #41# 46 | 266
>        33  49  41  59  20 #59#| 261
>        36  43 #21# 58  39  45 | 242
>       #63# 26  49  28  57  27 | 250
>       ------------------------
>       250 249 242 208 266 261   249
> ```

Now that we know which cells have to change, it is simple matter to change them to make the sums equal to 246. These changes indeed happen to be a permutation of those six numbers.

> ```
>                                 246
>        39  13  24  63  68  39 | 246
>        38  41  66  15  41  45 | 246
>        41  74  41  23  21  46 | 246
>        33  49  41  59  20  44 | 246
>        36  43  25  58  39  45 | 246
>        59  26  49  28  57  27 | 246
>       ------------------------
>       246 246 246 246 246 246   246
> ```